# Would like to refresh the extract for workbooks published to the Tableau server

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to refresh the extract for workbooks published in tableau server.

- Data source- Excel file

Error message:
Unable to connect to the file. Check that the file exists and that you have sufficient access privileges for it.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the location of the excel file is not reachable from the server (i.e. it's on your own pc). When you create your datasource from Tableau Desktop you have access to everything that's on your pc; when you publish it though, it will retain the same path (like "C:\users\your-user\documents\whatever") that on the server does not exist.

To solve this you have a few options:

1. save the file to a place that's accessible from the server, like the server itself or a network folder; this way the path will be valid when the datasource is published;
2. manually refresh the datasource by saving it as a local copy on your pc (thus giving meaning to that path again), refreshing it and then republishing it on the server replacing the old one

I would say most of the times option 1 is the way to go, but of course depends on your specific case.